# Парсинг даты Java

Tags: java, дата

Нужно из

```
String s = "12 12 2020";
```

сделать точно такую же дату, т.е. Date.

Не

```
Sat Dec 12 00:00:00 GMT+04:00 2020
```

А именно

```
12 12 2020
```

Уже всю голову сломал.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html метод parse

Comment: если  Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy").parse(s);
получится Sat Dec 12 00:00:00 GMT+04:00 2020

Comment: В java Date всегда со временем и с часовым поясом. Для обычной даты есть тип LocalDate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать DateTimeFormatter. Созданный мной паттерн парсит вашу дату, с его же помощью можно привести ее к исходному виду (как и сделано в приведенном мной коде). Если вывод должен отличаться, то напишите свой DateTimeFormatter аналогично моему, но с другим паттерном. И еще... переменные типа даты (будь то старый Date либо LocalDate) хранят лишь информацию. Строчное их представление определяется, как и в любом другом случае, методом toString. А для того, чтобы иметь возможность форматировать это самое строчное представление и служат классы типа DateTimeFormatter.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d M yyyy");        
String s = "12 12 2020";        
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(s, formatter);
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

Comment: К сожалению, нужен именно Date. Здесь же LocalDate, а в выводе, как я понимаю, стринга.

Comment: @CilitBang вы точно внимательно читали ответ? в выводе у вас в любом случае стринга (хотите вы этого или нет). вопрос только в том, как эта самая стринга будет сформирована. кроме того, класс Date давно устарел. Посему непонятно, кто диктует вам такие условия (объявлять переменные устаревших типов)? Хотя конвертировать достаточно просто: Date date = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

Comment: Такие условия диктует конструктор в задаче, иначе не пропускает. Я понимаю, что в выводе стринга. Понимаю, что в любом случае стринга.

Comment: @CilitBang это же задача, ее цель научить. что касается даты, в джаве в виду того, что класс Date, как и прочие классы, находящиеся в данном пакете, служащие для работы с датами/временем, крайне неудачны,очень давно использовали joda time, по сути в джаве 8 эта библиотека стала частью кора (превратилась в пакет java.time). теперь вы можете спарсить дату,вывести ее в нужном виде.ну а если так случиться, что интерфейс  какой-то устаревшей библиотеки потребует от вас именно Date,то дату всегда можно сконвертировать. Это случается не часто и лучше,чем использовать в своей логике устаревшие классы.

Comment: Большое спасибо, Дмитрий. С задачей я уже разобрался, решил. Я правильно понимаю, что сейчас актуал это  java.time и нужно почитать именно про этот пакет?

Comment: @CilitBang все верно , начиная с java 8 появился пакет java.time, на сегодняшний день ничего более нового не вышло. если у вас есть необходимость работать с датами/временем, то вам именно сюда - в пакет  java.time.

Comment: Спасибо, пойду изучать

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так,

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd yyyy");

String dateString = format.format( new Date()   );
Date   date       = format.parse ( "12 12 2020" );
```

Formatter даст вам перевести в Date. Есть изюминка с Date такая что каждая уважающая себя компания реализовала свой класс Date а всё из-за [этого](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_date.asp)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]