# Сконвертировать строку 202306222200 в LocalDateTime

Tags: java, spring

У меня есть сплошная строка "202306222200" из нее нужно сделать LocalDateTime вида "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm"

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+DateTimeFormatter). например [такой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1149369/178576) — буквально один в один.

Comment: а вообще вопросов тут два, причем никак друг с другом не связанных: 1. как преобразовать в дату строку в нужном формате. 2. как преобразовать дату в строку в нужном формате.

Comment: В других ответах есть хоть какой-то разделитель, а у меня сплошная строка

Comment: это не играет абсолютно никакой роли. `yyyyMMdd...и далее что там у вас ещё`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [как преобразовать дату в другой формат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1523492/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82)

Comment: пустой разделитель это точно такой же разделитель, как и любой другой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница с [указанным ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1523496/386633) только в том, что используются другие форматы и `LocalDateTime` вместо `LocalDate`:

```java
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;

// ...
String str = "202306222200";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
    "yyyyMMddHHmm"
);
DateTimeFormatter to = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");

LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);

System.out.println("Дата: " +  str + " -> " + d + " -> " + d.format(to));
```

Результат вывода:

```
Дата: 202306222200 -> 2023-06-22T22:00 -> 2023-06-22T22:00
```

Т.е. формат `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"` может использоваться также по умолчанию для дефолтной локали, см. [`LocalDateTime::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString--)